# JMeter REST Response is blank

Tags: jmeter

I have searched extensively for the solution of this problem but did not get enough information.  I am testing a GET request in REST API and although Sample Result is OK, I do not get any response in Response data tab.  A screenshot is attached.

I am getting this error - ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl: readResponse: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

I have no java code.  I know my REST API result is huge. (search result).  Please suggest how do I get around this problem?

Thank you
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCEsR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember facing this issue! Changing the implementation to `java/HttpClient4/3.1` in the HTTP requests will work.

[image]